# How can I retain a option from a select field?

Tags: php, html, html-select

I have a `<select>`:

```
<select id="countries">
<option value="1">USA</option>
<option value="2">Spain</option>
</select>
```

The user selects an option, then he press a send button to make a query, thru PHP. The result of the query appears in the same page, so the page reloads. 
How do i retain the selected option? when the page reloads??

I mean, if they select spain, how can I see spain again when the page reloads?

Answer (score 3):

You need to first give your select dropdown a name.

For example:

```
<select id="countries" name="countries">
```

Then you will have access to the value in your PHP when the form is submitted. The value can be retrieved like this in PHP (after submit):

```
$countries = $_POST['countries'];
```

Then you can do something like @JohnConde did by setting the selected attribute with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a *very* basic way to do it:

```
<option value="1"<?php if (1 === (int) $_POST['countries']) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>USA</option>
<option value="2"<?php if (2 === (int) $_POST['countries']) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Spain</option>
```